# How to add an App Store product page banner

Tags: unity-game-engine, app-store, app-store-connect

I use Unity for my apps.

Browsing the App Store I saw some apps, such as "Google Chrome" that have the background above the icon in the store listing.

My question is, how do I put it for my apps? With Android it is easy, there is the image to insert on Play Console, but on Apple I have not found anything about it.

Should I enter it via Unity? Or how should I do?

[image: 1]

Comment: You have to enter it in app store

Comment: @Jaimin There is no part to put it in, can you write an answer with an image? You will have your points as the correct answer, if it works..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't an option for this on App Store Connect. Apple reaches out to developers for whom they promote on the store or whose apps are featured in Stories on the App Store.

Read over the page here about being featured on the App Store: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/getting-featured/

*Side note*: you'll notice that most apps with App Store banners are either (A) from large companies (like Google, as noted in your question) or (B) have been repeatedly featured on the App Store (like 1Password).